# not getting expected result from python markdown

Tags: python, markdown

Probably, the problem is with my understanding of what is supposed to happen. Here's what I did:

```
>>> import markdown2
>>> rawtext = "Getting the Gist of Markdown's Formatting Syntax ------------------------------------------------ This page offers a brief "
>>> html = markdown2.markdown(rawtext)
>>> html
u"<p>Getting the Gist of Markdown's Formatting Syntax ------------------------------------------------ This page offers a brief </p>\n"
```

I tried using markdown instead of markdown2, but got the same result.  I would have expected the many "-"s to cause "Getting the Gist of Markdown's Formatting Syntax" to render as an H1.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll render as a `<h1>` only if the dashes are on their own line *below* the text:

```
>>> import markdown2
>>> rawtext = "Getting the Gist of Markdown's Formatting Syntax\n------------------------------------------------\nThis page offers a brief "
>>> markdown2.markdown(rawtext)
u"<h2>Getting the Gist of Markdown's Formatting Syntax</h2>\n\n<p>This page offers a brief </p>\n"
```

Comment: I am silly, and you are correct.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Insert some newlines:

```
rawtext = "Getting the Gist of Markdown's Formatting Syntax\n------------------------------------------------\nThis page offers a brief "
```

Markdown will only make the text before dashes into an `<h1>` if the dashes and the text are on a separate line. (Otherwise `Wow - I never knew that` would turn `Wow` into an `<h1>`.)